# QNetworkConfigurationManager::allConfigurations() doesn't list WLAN

Tags: c++, windows, qt, networking, wifi

Running under Windows 10, tested with two different Systems:

When i run `QNetworkConfigurationManager::allConfigurations()` I don't get any WLAN configuration, even if I'm connected actively to a **Wifi** Network.

Header:

```
public:
  NetworkManager(QObject* parent = 0);

private slots:
  void onNetworkConfigUpdate();

private:
  QNetworkConfiguration cfg;
  QList<QNetworkConfiguration> netcfgList;
  QNetworkConfigurationManager ncm;
```

.cpp

```
NetworkManager::NetworkManager(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) {
    ncm.updateConfigurations();
    connect(&ncm, SIGNAL(updateCompleted()), this,  SLOT(onNetworkConfigUpdate()));
}

void NetworkManager::onNetworkConfigUpdate() {
netcfgList = ncm.allConfigurations();
for (auto& x : netcfgList) {
    if (x.bearerType() == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN) {
        qDebug() << "Wifi found: " << x.name();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Something else: " << x.bearerType() << " - name: " << x.name();
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> Something else: 0 - name: "Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface"
>
> Something else: 1 - name: "Ethernet"
>
> Something else: 1 - name: "VirtualBox Host-Only Network"

I'm running on Windows 10; Qt 5.9.4 with MSVC2015

I checked with an Intel Wireless Card and an external USB Wifi-Stick. Why is it not showing any WLAN?

Comment: Win10, qt5.9.x, mingw .. your code is fine , it list WLAN (wifi) also!

Comment: On Windows our team used Win32 API for that about 3 years ago due to Qt not always listing WiFi and doing nothing besides listing. On Mac and Linux QNetworkConfigurationManager is good enough only to list WiFi but not actually use it. I now on Linux use NetworkManagerQt from KDE for basic WiFi operations e.g. authenticate and connect.

Comment: I also tried it with MinGW and the results are the same.

Comment: This is not surprising .. as you might noticed in the [Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkconfigurationmanager.html#allConfigurations) they have  a long note about `perform a WLAN scan` which for me the result is not guaranteed in case of, for example, weak singal! try to use `filter`

Comment: As you can see in the code, I am already using the update function (it is being called every few seconds) as mentioned in the link you posted. The Wifi connection is perfect (1m distance) and even when waiting for a long time and trying with different devices, it didn't work.

Comment: Yes I noticed. Did you check that interface? `QList<QNetworkInterface> interfceList = QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces();`

Comment: When I use `allConfigurations(QNetworkConfiguration::Defined);` I get faster and less varying results! give a try.

Comment: Thank you for you answers, Mohammad.  With QNetworkInterface, it does show a wireless interface indeed. The QNetworkConfiguration::Defined didn't change the results tho.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. To me was caused by a missing bearer plugin DLL.

To sort this out, I had to copy the QT "plugins/bearer" folder (containing qgenericbearer.dll and qnativewifibearer.dll) in my application root folder.

Like this:

- ApplicationFolder/

  - Application.exe
  - ...
  - Qt5Network.dll
  - bearer/

    - qgenericbearer.dll
    - qnativewifibearer.dll

Comment: running into the same problem. but my plugins/bearer has no qnativewifibearer.dll - only qgenericbearer.dll and qgenericbearerd.dll (Qt 5.12 RC with MSVC2017)